# Array of strings from single line in a file

Tags: c, arrays, string, fgets, strtok

I would like to get an array of strings from a .txt file. I tried using fgets then strtok to separate the strings. I think my fgets is wrong but I dont understand how to get to what I want.

```
char* str[numWords];
char line[] = fgets(str, numCharTotal, filep);
char delim[] = " ";
int j;
for(j = 0; j != numWords; j++)
{
       str[j]= strtok(line, delim);
}
```

In other words, I have a .txt file

```
This is a txt file
```

and I want to be able to have it in the form

```
char* str[] = {"This","is","a","txt","file"};

printf("%s", str[0])  //then "This" is printed
//...
//Till last word of txt file
//...
printf("%s", str[4])  //then "file" is printed
```

Comment: Is `numCharTotal` so large that it actually reads in the entire line? In that case you need to loop `strtok` over the part that it read. Currently you are discarding everything else after the first found space.

Comment: numCharTotal would be (the number of chars in the biggest word + 1) in the txt file. In this case, it would be 4+1 = 5.

Comment: But that is going to *always* be the number of characters read, spaces or no spaces. You'd have to reposition the file pointer if it's off. You are better off to read the entire line at once and *then* use a (perfectly standard) `strtok` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[fgets](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) will read a line from your file and store it in a string. You need to allocate memory for you buffer (char array line in your code). After calling strtok with the char array line as the first parameter, loop through calling [strtok](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) passing in NULL for the first parameter. If you continue to pass the char array line, you will only get the first token (word) for each iteration of the loop.

```
char *str[numWords];
char line[numCharTotal];
char delim[] = " ";
int j = 0;

fgets(line, numCharTotal, filep);

char *token = strtok(line, delim);
while (token != NULL) {
    str[j] = token;
    ++j;
    token = strtok(NULL, delim);
}

for (int i = 0; i < numWords; ++i) {
    printf("%s\n", str[i]);
}
```

Comment: Should my numCharTotal be ALL the chars in that first line?

Comment: Yes, have it large enough to store everything in the line in the file + 1.

Comment: Printing the value of str[j] prints the pointer, how would I print the actual word?

Comment: If you run a for loop like in the example above you will print each word from the line imported from your text file.

Comment: What is your format specifier in your printf statement? If it is "%s" it would not print the pointer but the string, effectively dereferencing your pointer. If you are using this inside a function and then using the value of str outside you will need to allocate memory.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the statement:

```
line = fgets(str, numCharTotal, filep);
```

Outside of the loop, and use the loop to read 'line' one word at a time.

Currently, the first iteration of your loop reads the first line, then the first word. And then the other iterations will try to read the next lines of the file, which are empty